# Javascript : hide and show toggle button on <td> restores while page is loading

Tags: javascript, html

I have a scenario like, there's a plain <**table**> <**td**> tags in my jsp page, between which I need to toggle hide-n-show, once click on a <**a href..**> hyperlink. I did the toggle using plain javascript function (not jQuery) and it's working okay.

But the problem that I'm facing is, while doing some operations in <**td**>, it use to reload the page and hence it's resetting the toggled state.

The code in jsp (with *custom-tag*) is :

```
<a id="toggleLinkId" href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleTable();" >Toggle Table</a>
    <td colspan="2" id="id1" style="display: none">
    <query:SingleQueryRecord editUrl="<%=editURL%>" extraparameters='<%=searchURL%>'/>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" id="id2" >
    <query:QueryDataTable editUrl="<%=editURL%>" />
    </td>
```

Here, once clicked in '`toggleLinkId`' link, it calls the javascript function '`toggleTable()`'.
But after doing manipulations, it reloads and resets the toggled <**td**>, because of the ' `style="display: none"` ' , which is required for the first time page load.

The javascript I wrote is a simple one:

```
function toggleTable(){
    
    if( document.getElementById('id1').style.display == 'none' ){
       document.getElementById('id2').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('id1').style.display = 'block';
     } else{
       document.getElementById('id1').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('id2').style.display = 'block';
    }
    
}
```

I hope I can state clearly my problem. If any suggestions you can give to retain the toggled state even after the page reloads, it will be really helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: `restores while page is loading` - because there's no memory of a state a page is in when you reload it

Comment: Can you give any code example, how to get that **memory of state**. Thanks.

Comment: you could use `cookies` or preferably,  `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` - up to you how you store and retrieve it - i.e. what you want to store and retrieve is up to you

Comment: okay I need to store the values in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` to retrieve it. Let me try with that.

Comment: Two approaches : save the state either in sessionStorage or localStorage or database; on the click reload only the target content, and not the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a LocalStorage example.
I hope I have been helpful

```
// First check if there is data saved in localStorage
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("localStorageMyData");

// ...and if there is data execute them
if (retrievedData) {
    var myValue = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
    var id1 = myValue.id1;
    var id2 = myValue.id2;

    document.getElementById('id1').setAttribute('style', id1);
    document.getElementById('id2').setAttribute('style', id2);
}

function toggleTable() {

    if (document.getElementById('id1').style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('id2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('id1').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('id1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('id2').style.display = 'block';
    }

    // The information is saved in localStorage with each click
    var id1 = document.getElementById('id1').getAttribute("style");
    var id2 = document.getElementById('id2').getAttribute("style");

    var myValue = ({ id1: id1, id2: id2 });
    localStorage.setItem("localStorageMyData", JSON.stringify(myValue));
    
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank u. It will help.

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful :) You can mark this answer as accepted answer.